How do I show countries using paths on a 3d globe - React Native
I'm trying to create an interactive world map in React Native. I have a file called countriesData.json and it comes with country information paths in the following format. The 3D globe I created with the help of @react-three/fiber works successfully, but I cannot show the countries on the globe using country paths.
// countriesData.json example
[{
    "name": "Germany",
    "id": "de",
    "path": "M 564.4 347.9 564.3 347.8 564 347.1 564.2 347.1 564.4 347.9 Z"
  },
  {
    "name": "United States",
    "id": "us",
    "path": "M 574.9 347.4 574.5 348 574.1 348 574.3 347.7 574.4 347.1 574.8 346.8 574.9 347.2 574.9 347.4 Z"
  }]

import {Canvas} from '@react-three/fiber';
import useControls from 'r3f-native-orbitcontrols';
import React, {Suspense} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import Model from './src/Model';

const App = () => {
  const [OrbitControls, events] = useControls();

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#000'}} {...events}>
      <Canvas style={{flex: 1}}>
        <OrbitControls enableRotate minZoom={1.5} maxZoom={3} />
        <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
        <directionalLight
          intensity={0.5}
          position={[0.5, 1, 10]}
          args={['#9e9e9e', 2]}
        />
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <Model />
        </Suspense>
      </Canvas>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;

import React from 'react';
import countriesData from './countriesData.json';

export default function Model() {
  return (
    <group dispose={null} scale={1}>
      <mesh castShadow receiveShadow position={[0, 0, 0]} scale={[1, 1, 1]}>
        <sphereGeometry args={[1, 32, 32]} />
        <meshStandardMaterial color="#65A3FF" />
        <directionalLight intensity={0.5} position={[0.5, 1, 10]} />
      </mesh>
    </group>
  );
}

The sphere appears and works successfully. What I just want to do is to show the countries on the globe using paths. Also, when I click it, it should print the name of the country on the console.

It's a geographic problem, about map projection.

The first step is to understand the basic of projection, you wrap planar representation (in your case SVG) on a 3D sphere, this YT video illustrates it perfectly.
Then regarding your sample data for US and Germany, the coordinates seems to overlap, meaning that those data "lost" their mapped reference coordinates. If you where to put the coordinates of all your countries on the same SVG files, they should make a full map, but with those actual data they would overlap. At this step, you might want to go for TopoJSON or GeoJSON (example here).

const response = await fetch(
  "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/world-atlas@1/world/50m.json"
);
const topology = await response.json();


If you want to stick with SVG, once you have data with same reference, you can split each path of your SVGs that are on a plane, a Cartesian representation and map them to Spherical, see Converting Between Cartesian Coordinates and Spherical Coordinates. Example here.

